# Behavior of solutions to a linear differential system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

If I have a system $x' = Ax$ of linear differential equations with constant coefficients, what happens if the time goes to infinity? I mean how would the eigenvalues of $A$ look like?

Comment: The short answer? It depends.

Comment: I was thinking that if $t$ goes to an infinity then $\frac {dx}{dt} = 0$ and I am just solving the homogenous system $Ax = 0$.

Comment: That is certainly not true in general. It's all about the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$. See Johan's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the solution is given by $ x(t) = \exp(At)x_0 $, with $$ \exp(At) := \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^kt^k}{k!} $$
If we suppose that A is diagonalizable, $A=P^{-1}DP$, with D a diagonal matrix, we have $$ \exp(At)=P^{-1}\exp(Dt)P=P^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix} 
e^{\lambda_1 t} &\cdots &  0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & e^{\lambda_nt}
\end{pmatrix}
P $$

So if all the eigenvalues are strictly negative, then $\lim \limits_{t \to \infty} x(t)=0$

and it will also be true if $x_0$ is a linear combinaison of only eigenvectors of strictly negative eigenvalues.

Edit : if all eigenvalues are negative or zero, then $\lim \limits_{t \to \infty} exp(Dt)$ converges so  you can easily find $\lim \limits_{t \to \infty} x(t)$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand it now.